# How to trigger editor programmatically

Tags: tabulator

I have set up a producttable (kind of a shopping-cart) with one editable column (product amount) like this :

```
{
    title:"Aantal", 
    field:"product_amount", 
    align:"center", 
    responsive: 3, 
    validator:["required","numeric"], 
    editor:amountEditor, 
    cellEdited:recalcPrices, 
    validator:["required","numeric","min:1","max:10"]
},
```

I am using a custom jquery amountEditor because this one looks somewhat nicer than the builtin editor. Rows are added to the shopping cart tabel (copied from another producttable) by a button click. Everything works fine but I would like that the user doesn't have to click on the editable columnfield himself. So the only one editable field should be triggered automatically / programmatically after the row is added to the table.

I think I have to combine these commands somehow in the table definition:

```
rowAdded:function(row){
    var cell = row.getCell("product_amount"); 
    cell.edit();
},
```

I tried everything but I cannot find the right combination to get this work. I can get var rowElement = row.getElement(), however var cells = row.getCells() or var cell = row.getCell(column) look empty. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to scroll to the row using the ***scrollTo*** function on the row component to ensure it is visible before you can trigger an edit on the cell, so your ***rowAdded*** callback wants to look like this:

```
rowAdded:function(row){
    row.scrollTo().then(function(){
        row.getCell("product_amount").edit();
    });
},
```

Comment: You are a genius Oli. Thx a lot.